# Count or sum specific string (strings) in each row (rowwise) using dplyr

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, dplyr

Let's say I have this dataset

```
ds <- data.frame(X1 = c("TP","TP","FN","FN"),
             X2 = c("TP","TP","FN","FN"),
             X3 = c("TN","TN","FP","FP"),
             X4 = c("FP","TN","FP","FP"))
```

I would like to count how many "TP" "FN" (etc) are in each row and achieve this result:
[image: table]

I have tried to use `mutate(total_TP= sum(str_detect(select(X1:X4), "TP")))` but it's not working.

I would like to remain within tidyverse environment.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. You can compute the variables and then merge. You can do all of this using `dplyr`. You will also require formating the data with `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()`. These functions belong to `tidyr`. Previous packages are loaded when calling `tidyverse`. You can create the summary variables and then joining creating a common id variable. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Code
ds %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  left_join(ds %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
              group_by(id,value) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from=N)) %>%
  select(-id) %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 TP FP TN FN
1 TP TP TN FP  2  1  1  0
2 TP TP TN TN  2  0  2  0
3 FN FN FP FP  0  2  0  2
4 FN FN FP FP  0  2  0  2
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(ds, mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(ds))))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 FN FP TN TP
#V1 TP TP TN FP  0  1  1  2
#V2 TP TP TN TN  0  0  2  2
#V3 FN FN FP FP  2  2  0  0
#V4 FN FN FP FP  2  2  0  0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(ds, as.data.frame.matrix(table(c(row(ds)), unlist(ds))))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` with `pmap` and `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
ds %>%
     mutate(new = pmap(., ~ table(factor(c(...), levels = c("FN", "FP", "TN", "TP"))))) %>% 
     unnest_wider(c(new))
# A tibble: 4 x 8
#  X1    X2    X3    X4       FN    FP    TN    TP
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 TP    TP    TN    FP        0     1     1     2
#2 TP    TP    TN    TN        0     0     2     2
#3 FN    FN    FP    FP        2     2     0     0
#4 FN    FN    FP    FP        2     2     0     0
```

Comment: Happy to see you here, @akrun! I did not know this qdapTools! Thanks for sharing this knowledge with me (us!). By the way, motivated with some of the previous discussions here in this forum, I've also started to learn python! =) [Hope to see you someday helping on this new knowledge too =P =P ] Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

One option utilizing `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
ds %>%
 bind_cols(map_dfc(.x = unique(unlist(ds)),
                   ~ ds %>%
                    transmute(!!.x := rowSums(select(., everything()) == .x))))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 TP FN TN FP
1 TP TP TN FP  2  0  1  1
2 TP TP TN TN  2  0  2  0
3 FN FN FP FP  0  2  0  2
4 FN FN FP FP  0  2  0  2
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution as well!